# Inconsistent module version for global modules when retrieving modules using Get-AzureRmAutomationModule cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I'm observing the following behavior when trying to retrieve Automation modules from automation account using Get-AzureRmAutomationModule cmdlet.

When using the cmdlet with only 2 parameters (ResourceGroupName and AutomationAccountName), the modules list shows Version as null for the "**global**" modules. However, when running the same cmdlet by passing 3 parameters (ResourceGroupName, AutomationAccountName, and Module name), we get the version for the global modules.

Is this as designed and if so, why is it in this way? Currently, the portal also shows version as null for the global modules when in fact they have a version already. Some sample modules where this behavior is seen are listed below.

```
AuditPolicyDsc
PSDscResources
SecurityPolicyDsc
StateConfigCompositeResources
xDSCDomainjoin
xPowerShellExecutionPolicy
xRemoteDesktopAdmin
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some personal opinions for you to refer, I think it may be a **bug** of the API.

First, I check it in the portal and test the command, the result is like you mentioned, but the command is essentially an API. So I check my automation account in the **azure resource explorer**(choose the `AuditPolicyDsc` module for sample).

Check all the **modules**:

[image]

Check only the `AuditPolicyDsc` module:

[image]

You could find the `AuditPolicyDsc` module, not only the `version`, but also the `sizeInBytes` and `activityCount` are different.

**Note**: Also, I think it may not be related to **global**, you could find a module named `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core`, it is **global** but the version is **not null**.

[image]

They use two different API, I think it may caused by them, otherwise it may be unreasonable.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/{automationAccount}/modules?api-version=2015-10-31

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/{automationAccount}/modules/AuditPolicyDsc?api-version=2015-10-31
```

If you want to improve it, I think you could post idea in the [automation feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation), it may be helpful.

Comment: Hello Joy. Yes, I also believe this could be a bug. But 2 things related to what you mentioned, 1) About global modules, what I meant was, this behavior I'm seeing only in global modules and I agree, it's not for all global modules. 2) The 2 URLs that you've provided, I believe the first one is for the generic cmdlet without any specific module name and the other is for a particular module name; otherwise, they're pretty much same.

Comment: @AmoghNatu Yes, so I think it is a bug,1) I know what you mean, if it was designed, it will for all global modules, right? 2) Yes, what I mean is the bug between generic cmdlet and specific module, otherwise it is hard to explain.

Comment: I've raised the issue on github and the team has confirmed this to be an issue. more updates yet to come. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6846

Comment: @AmoghNatu You could mark it for other community members to find.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I intended to mark it but just put the comment and missed. Thanks for the detailed investigation in the answer though!